# Error while running Play 2.0 application on Java 1.8.0_65

Tags: java, playframework

Getting the following error -

```
$ play run
error: error while loading AnnotatedElement, class file 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_65\lib\rt.jar(java/lang/reflect/AnnotatedElement.class)' is broken
(bad constant pool tag 15 at byte 2682)
[error] Type error in expression
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?
```